# Get parameters from url parse

Tags: php, frameworks, parse-url

I want to get parameters from url but i dont know how can do it.

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])["path"];
```

I get the url with this code block. Its give me link like that

> /movies/2/delete

I want to learn deleting 2 id movies from router. But i can't parse this query.

I want to a algorithm for example;

```
if(startWith($url,"/movies"))
{
   $parameter=getParameter($url,"/movies/{id}")["id"];
   if(getMethod($url)==="delete") deleteMovie($parameter);
   //bla bla...
}
```

Comment: So, `explode` your url and get required items.

Comment: I know bro, but i want generate a basic routing class.

Comment: You tagged this `frameworks`. If you're using a framework, it will usually do the routing for you, you don't need to parse the URL yourself. Add a tag for the framework you're using, and someone should be able to help you with it.

Comment: which framework?

Comment: I want to generate framework myself